# Get the new added row values for insert in grid control devexpress winform

Tags: winforms, devexpress

i'am actually trying to get the new values of the new added row from my grid control (devexpress) thant i set "AllowAddRows" to true;
i can get the updated one like this

> Object row = ListeQual.GetRow(ListeQual.FocusedRowHandle);

but i can get the new values in add event for insert

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button how allow  to add new row :

```
  private void AddNewRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // (ListeQual.MainView as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView).AddNewRow();
             ListeQual.AddNewRow(); 
        }
```

And a create a methode how you can pass the new row as parameter for saving in datatbase :

```
private int insertData(DataRow dr)
    {
        string connectionString = "your connection string here";
        int nb = 0;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Data (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (@col1, @col2, @col3)");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", dr[0]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", dr[1]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col3", dr[2]);
            connection.Open();
           nb= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return nb;
    }
```

Finally  you can handle the event `ValidateRow` :

```
 private void ListeQual_ValidateRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ValidateRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView view = ListeQual as GridView;
            if (view.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle))
            {
              DataRow dw = view.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);
              insertData(dw);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What  is the datasource of your gridView ?

Comment: List<QUALIFICATIONS> ListeQualification = BD.QUALIFICATIONS.ToList(); this.GridControlQualification.DataSource = ListeQualification;

Comment: For add a new row in GridView : ListeQual.AddNewRow();

Comment: where can i add this line ? and how can i get the passed values to insert in database

Comment: Ok I modified my answer with exemple when you can use  ListeQual.AddNewRow();  and an exemple for insert to datatbase .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void ListeQual_ValidateRow(object sender, ValidateRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if (view.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle))
    {
        DataRow row = view.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't hit this methode in debugging mode

Comment: how you add the new row with the code or in the grid with UI ?